# Searching for Literature and References for specific IMEX-Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I have a question regarding IMEX-Methods.
I know that for an ordinary differential equation of the form
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}(t)=f(y)+g(y) $$
we can use an explicit method for $f(y)$ which is typically a non-linear but also non-stiff term and for $g(y)$ we use an implicit method which is usually a linear and stiff term.
$$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\triangle t \left( f(y_{n}+g(y_{n+1})\right)$$
I am looking for something similar, where the ODE is not divided into a sum but a product.
$$\frac{dy}{dt}(t)=f(y)g(y)$$
and to solve such equations like this
$$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\triangle t \left( f(y_{n})g(y_{n+1})\right)$$
I don't seem to find literatures that investigate such forms of IMEX methods.

Can someone can recommened me some references where I can find more information about such problems?